# Dynamic dropdown and save cakephp code not working together

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have three tables 'Categories' , 'Courses' and 'Subjects' with following associations

1. Category hasMany Course
2. Course BelongsTo Category, Course hasMany Subject
3. Subject BelongsTo Course, Subject hasMany Notes
4. Notes BelongsTo Subject

When I try to save the data it's giving the error
'Call to a member function create() on null'.

```
class SubjectsController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Category','Course');

    public function add(){
        pr($this->request->data);die;
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            pr($this->request->data);die;
            $this->Subject->create();
            if ($this->Subject->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The subject has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The subject could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your Ajax. It's telling you right in the error message. You're trying to call the `create` function from a `null` object. In this case, `$this->Subject`.

You have `$this->uses` the Category and Course models, but not Subject. You can either add that to the list of what this controller uses, or you can get to it via the existing association with something you're already using: `$this->Course->Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the retrieved data is correct an than do it like this:

```
$this->Subject->create();
$this->Subject->set(array($this->request->data);
$this->Subject->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply got the answer